# C++ SDL image gets black and disappears

Tags: sdl

I started writing a little game but something with the image is not working. They're working fine at the beginning but after some moments there become black and then they disappear.
Don't be worried about the long code the relevant things with the images happen mostly in the following methods: `build_mode_draw()` and `play_mode_draw()`.

I tested the program with a blue cube instead of a image and it worked fine

Probably I don't really understand how the image gets loaded

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define WindowWidth 1500
#define WindowHight 800

#define ArrayGrosseBuildMode 100

#define StartFensterBlockmenge 10    // in Plockgröße bezüglich der kleineren Achse

bool end = false;
bool programm_part_run = true;

unsigned int play_mode_speed = 0;

unsigned int counter;
unsigned int counter_2;
unsigned int counter_3;

unsigned int blocksize;
unsigned int blocks_fit_in_X;
unsigned int blocks_fit_in_Y;

unsigned int play_mode_blockamount;
//unsigned int blockamount = 0;

bool build_mode_block_pos[ArrayGrosseBuildMode][ArrayGrosseBuildMode];

unsigned int play_mode_block_pos_X[WindowWidth]; // Fächer beschreiben
unsigned int play_mode_block_pos_Y[WindowHight]; //         ||


//mouse variables
unsigned short int pressed_mouse_button = 0; // 0 = no , 1 = left , mouse Button pressed
unsigned int MouseX;
unsigned int MouseY;

//keyboard variables

//set window 

SDL_Window* window = NULL;

//set renderer

SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

//set event

SDL_Event event;

void input()
{
 SDL_PollEvent(&event);

 // reset variables
 pressed_mouse_button = 0; // set to no mouse button pressed

 switch(event.type)
 {
  case SDL_QUIT:
  end = true;
  programm_part_run = false;
  break;
  case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
  MouseX = event.motion.x;
  MouseY = event.motion.y;
  break;
  case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
  switch(event.button.button)
  {
   case SDL_BUTTON_LEFT:
   pressed_mouse_button = 1;
   break;
  }
  break;
  case SDL_KEYDOWN:
  switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
  {
   case SDLK_SPACE:
   programm_part_run = false;
   break;
  }
 }
}

void put_build_mode_grid_in_renderer()
{
 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);

 for(counter = 0; counter <= blocks_fit_in_Y; counter = counter + 1)
 {
  SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer,0,counter * blocksize,blocks_fit_in_X*blocksize,counter * blocksize);
 }
 for(counter = 0; counter <= blocks_fit_in_X; counter = counter + 1)
 {
  SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer,counter * blocksize,0,counter * blocksize,blocks_fit_in_Y*blocksize);
 }
}

void build_mode_draw()
{
 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 0);
 SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

 put_build_mode_grid_in_renderer();

 SDL_Surface * image = SDL_LoadBMP("stealcube.bmp");
 SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,image);
 SDL_FreeSurface(image);

 for(counter = 0; counter <= blocks_fit_in_X; counter = counter + 1)
 {
  for(counter_2 = 0; counter_2 <= blocks_fit_in_Y; counter_2 = counter_2 + 1)
  {
   if(build_mode_block_pos[counter][counter_2] == true)
   {
   SDL_Rect dstrect = { counter * blocksize, counter_2 * blocksize, blocksize, blocksize}; 
   SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &dstrect);
   }
  }
 }
 SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void build_mode()
{

 while(programm_part_run)
 {
  input();
  if(pressed_mouse_button == 1)
  {
   build_mode_block_pos[MouseX/blocksize][MouseY/blocksize] = true;
  }
  build_mode_draw();
 }
}

void play_mode_draw()
{ 
 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 0);
 SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

 SDL_Surface * image = SDL_LoadBMP("stealcube.bmp");
 SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,image);
 SDL_FreeSurface(image);

 for(counter = 0; counter < play_mode_blockamount; counter = counter + 1)
 {
  SDL_Rect dstrect = { play_mode_block_pos_X[counter], play_mode_block_pos_Y[counter], blocksize, blocksize};
  SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &dstrect);
 }
 SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void play_mode()
{
 counter_3 = 0;
 for(counter = 0; counter <= blocks_fit_in_X; counter = counter + 1)
 {
  for(counter_2 = 0; counter_2 <= blocks_fit_in_Y; counter_2 = counter_2 + 1)
  {
   if(build_mode_block_pos[counter][counter_2] == true)
   {
    play_mode_block_pos_X[counter_3] = counter*blocksize;
    play_mode_block_pos_Y[counter_3] = counter_2*blocksize;
    counter_3 = counter_3 + 1;
   }
  }
 }
 play_mode_blockamount = counter_3;

 while(programm_part_run)
 {
  for(counter = 0; counter < play_mode_speed; counter = counter + 1)
  {
  input();
  SDL_Delay(1);
  }

  for(counter = 0; counter <= play_mode_blockamount; counter = counter + 1)
  {
   if(play_mode_block_pos_Y[counter] < blocks_fit_in_Y * blocksize - blocksize)
   {
    play_mode_block_pos_Y[counter] = play_mode_block_pos_Y[counter] + 1;
   }
  }
  play_mode_draw();
 }
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
 SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

 window = SDL_CreateWindow
 (
  "Test Fenster :)", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
  SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
  WindowWidth,
  WindowHight,
  SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
 );

 renderer =  SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

 //setup

 if(WindowWidth < WindowHight)
 {
  blocksize = WindowWidth/StartFensterBlockmenge;
 }
 else
 {
  blocksize = WindowHight/StartFensterBlockmenge;
 }

 blocks_fit_in_X = WindowWidth/blocksize;
 blocks_fit_in_Y = WindowHight/blocksize;

 while(!end)
 {
  programm_part_run = true;

  build_mode();

  programm_part_run = true;

  play_mode();

 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You mention that only parts of the code you have posted have to do with the problematic image. It would be best if you reduced the code you have posted to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem. While you're at it, check out this help center article on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions.

Comment: I have no idea wats the problem so I cant say that some part of the code is unimportand I just wanted to give a startingpoint for problemsolving.

Comment: Possible problem is that alpha is 0 in `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` at line 1 of the `play_mode_draw()` method

Comment: thanks for the answer I just testet how that works so I was not able to see witch sense the last sektor makes

Comment: I changed the 0 in to 255 but the problem was not solved

Comment: I changed  SDL_PollEvent(&event);  in  void input() first line  in to SDL_WaitEvent(&event); and the images dont get black ore disapere but I dont knew how this thinks work together and I neat to use SDL_PollEvent(&event);  for the programm